# How to call streaming API from Azure Logic Apps?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

Is there any way that I can use Azure Logic Apps to call streaming APIs? The API doesn't support chunking parameter so `Range` header is not an option.
I am looking for a logic similar to Python Requests library's `Response.iter_content()` that I can iterate over response data in chunks and write them back in DB.

**My desired workflow**: The logic app gets triggered once a day at a specific time. It calls the streaming API using HTTP connector and streams in all the data (data is much larger than HTTP connector internal buffer size). The API supports stream request and I am able to iterate through response in chunks using python `Response.iter_content(chunk_size=1048576)` to fetch them all.

PS: I know I can use Azure function and have it triggered within my Logic App workflow, but I'd prefer to use Logic Apps native connectors.

Comment: This is a really open ended question. Do you want the logic app to constantly stream? Where is the data coming from? Is the logic app to stream out or in? Can you add more detail?

Comment: @Skin I updated the question and added my workflow.

Comment: But what is the “steaming API”? It’s still not possible to answer the question. You need to provide screenshots and more technical information relating to the problem you’re facing. Who is the provider of the API?

Comment: I am not sure why the API is important here! I want to see if logic apps have a connector that can call an API and get the response header only and then iterate through response content in chunks similar to standard programming languages streaming clients.

Comment: Because you used the word “streaming”. Of course it can do what you just said in your last comment but if that’s the case, it’s not streaming, it’s just standard request and response that is batched up in chunks. Streaming is  typically pushed on a very frequent basis. So to answer your question, yes it can do it. Now back to the API, to have that makes it easier for us to help. If you want an answer that’s like for like, it’s handy to provide us with as much info as possible to give you an answer. As of right now, the answer to your comment is **yes**.

Comment: From what I read, we have a similar requirement. The documentation of the API refers to this link : https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tutorials/consuming-streaming-data . one GET request is done, and the answer comes continuously. What PaaS component would be able to handle such a use case ?